# Elasticsearch error : Root type mapping not empty after parsing! Remaining fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to insert a new type 'place' in elasticsearch using its curl API. But it keeps failing.
The command I'm using is:

```
curl -XPUT host/my_index/_mapping/place --data
'{
    "place": {
        "_id": {
            "path": "place_id"
        },
        "properties": {
            "place_id":{
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "store": true
            },
            "location": {
                "type": "geo_point",
                "store": true
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": true
            },
            "address": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": true
            },
            "city": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": true
            },
            "state": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": true
            },
            "postal_code": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": true
            },
            "phone": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "phone_number",
                "store": true
            },
            "update_time": {
                "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[Root type mapping not empty after parsing! Remaining fields:   [place : {_id={path=place_id}, properties={place_id={type=string, index=not_analyzed, store=true}, location={type=geo_point, store=true}, name={type=string, store=true}, address={type=string, store=true}, city={type=string, store=true}, state={type=string, store=true}, postal_code={type=string, store=true}, phone={type=string, analyzer=phone_number, store=true}, update_time={format=dateOptionalTime, type=date}}}]]","status":400}%
```

Nothing looks wrong to me ... What is the problem?

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE**:

This is the current mapping of the index

```
{
  index: {
    mappings: {
      image: {
        _id: {
          path: "image_id"
        },
        properties: {
          caption: {
            type: "string"
          },
          comments: {
            properties: {
              count: {
                type: "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          creation_time: {
            type: "date",
            format: "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          is_tag_search: {
            type: "boolean"
          },
          image_id: {
            type: "string",
            index: "not_analyzed"
          },
          likes: {
            properties: {
              count: {
                type: "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          location: {
            type: "geo_point",
            lat_lon: true
          },
          logos: {
            type: "string"
          },
          social_score: {
            type: "float"
          },
          source: {
            type: "string",
            analyzer: "keyword_lowercase"
          },
          tags: {
            type: "string",
            analyzer: "tags",
            fields: {
              raw: {
                type: "string",
                index: "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          url: {
            type: "string",
            index: "no"
          }
        }
      },
      tag: {
        _id: {
        path: "tag_id"
      },
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: "string"
        },
        suggest: {
          type: "completion",
          analyzer: "simple",
          payloads: true,
          preserve_separators: true,
          preserve_position_increments: true,
          max_input_length: 50
        },
        tag_id: {
          type: "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check to see if you don't have any dynamic templates or something like that in your index already. `GET /my_index/_mapping`

Comment: No, I don't think I have any of those.

Comment: Then can you update the question with the `_mapping` of that index?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, for me it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be as simple as removing the newline character you have between the first and the second line:

From this:

```
curl -XPUT host/my_index/_mapping/place --data
'{
```

To this:

```
curl -XPUT host/my_index/_mapping/place --data '{
```

I copy/pasted your exact command above and it failed for me. Then I removed the newline and it worked.